# Excessive lag when loading view controller containing Core Plot graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I've just started using Core Plot, and for testing have a `CPTGraphHostingView` embedded in a simple custom view controller, plotting values from a Core Data fetchRequest (it's an app graphing dietary calorie intake per day).

The code is mostly pasted in from the tutorial [here](http://www.mobdevel.com/?p=96).

The problem is the UI freezing for around two seconds when pushing the view controller into view (it's embedded in a navigation controller). This is when run on a device (iPhone 4S).

Profiling in Instruments reveals that the main thread is being blocked by `[CPTAxis layoutSublayers]` and `[CPTLayer drawInContext]`.

The lag is not due to an excessively large dataset: it currently contains precisely two points. The graph is *extremely* simple and looks like this:

[image]

Complete implementation of the view controller:

Interface:

```
//
//  ICCaloriesGraphController.h
//  iCalories
//
//  Created by David Fearon on 22/08/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 David Fearon. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
#import "ICDatabaseBrain.h"
#import "Day.h"
#import "CalorieEntry.h"

@interface ICCaloriesGraphController : UIViewController<CPTPlotDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *graphHostingView;
@property (nonatomic, retain)ICDatabaseBrain* sharedDatabaseBrain;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSFetchedResultsController* resultsController;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
//
//  ICCaloriesGraphController.m
//  iCalories
//
//  Created by David Fearon on 22/08/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 David Fearon. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ICCaloriesGraphController.h"

@interface ICCaloriesGraphController ()

@property int numberOfRecordsForPlot;
@property float maxDailyCaloriesInDataset;
@property NSArray* days;

@end

@implementation ICCaloriesGraphController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sharedDatabaseBrain = [ICDatabaseBrain sharedDatabaseBrain];
    self.resultsController = self.sharedDatabaseBrain.fetchDaysResultsController;

    self.days = [self.resultsController fetchedObjects];
    self.numberOfRecordsForPlot = [self.days count];

    [self updateMaxDailyCaloriesInDataset];

    // Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
    CPTGraph* graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.graphHostingView.bounds];
    self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    // Get the (default) plotspace from the graph so we can set its x/y ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // Note that these CPTPlotRange are defined by START and LENGTH (not START and END) !!
    [plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( self.maxDailyCaloriesInDataset )]];
    [plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( self.numberOfRecordsForPlot )]];

    // Create the plot (we do not define actual x/y values yet, these will be supplied by the datasource...)
    CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Let's keep it simple and let this class act as datasource (therefore we implement <CPTPlotDataSource>)
    plot.dataSource = self;

    // Finally, add the created plot to the default plot space of the CPTGraph object we created before
    [self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:self.graphHostingView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plotnumberOfRecords {
    return self.numberOfRecordsForPlot;
}


-(void)updateMaxDailyCaloriesInDataset{

    if (self.numberOfRecordsForPlot == 0){
        self.maxDailyCaloriesInDataset = 0;
        return;
    }

    int max = 0;

    for (Day* day in self.days) {

        //count the calories in the day:
        int calorieSum = 0;
        for (CalorieEntry* calorieEntry in [day.calorieEntries allObjects]) {
            calorieSum += calorieEntry.calories.intValue;
        }

        if(calorieSum > max) max = calorieSum;

    }

    self.maxDailyCaloriesInDataset = max;

}


-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if (self.numberOfRecordsForPlot == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY){

        Day* day = [self.days objectAtIndex:index];

        //count the calories in the day:
        int calorieSum = 0;
        for (CalorieEntry* calorieEntry in [day.calorieEntries allObjects]) {
            calorieSum += calorieEntry.calories.intValue;
        }

        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:calorieSum];
        //TODO: Set range for y axis

    }

    if(fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX){
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt: index];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"fieldEnum was neither CPTScatterPlotFieldY or CPTScatterPlotFieldX in numberForPlot:");
        return 0;
    }

}

@end
```

The lag is definitely nothing to do with the Core Data code; that all works fine. Googling around this only shows up problems with huge datasets, not ones with only two points. Obviously I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with the Core Plot code but really can't see what.

Can anybody spot the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `maxDailyCaloriesInDataset` large? The default axis labeling policy puts tick marks and labels one unit apart along the axis. If the `yRange` is large, this creates a lot of overlapping labels, which can be very slow. Depending on the requirements of your app, either increase the `majorIntervalLength` so it doesn't make so many labels, or change the labeling policy. `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` and `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions` would be good choices.

Comment: It was indeed large - that was it. I was thinking it was something around that area but the documentation is austere, to say the least. Thanks Eric.